# What are the alternatives to Socket Programming?

Tags: c#, sockets

I was browsing around for programming troubleshooters, and I was wondering what the alternate would be for Socket Programming; if there is one.

Comment: I think it would help if you clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  What do you consider an "alternate" to socket programming?  Do you mean an alternate to machine-to-machine communication or a broader scale including internet communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have control over the protocol being used, you could go for a higher level of abstraction like .NET's Remoting or WCF.

Comment: Don't waste your time with Remoting.  It's being deprecated.

Comment: Hmm deprecated in favor of what?

Comment: jro, Mono's WCF support is limited, so Remoting is the only choice if you care about Mono.

Answer (score 2):

[TCPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [UDPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) abstract you from the underlying sockets to some degree. They're nice to work with.

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather vague and does not explain what MrM's issues with socket programming are, or what he is trying to accomplish.

An actual alternative to sockets would e.g. be [**(Win)Pcap**](http://www.winpcap.org/), for which .net wrappers exist and that does not sit on top of the socket layer, as the other answers given so far.

There is also [**RDMA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access), which also does not use sockets, or much of the network stack at all, geared towards highest performance, but is not compatible with common IP networking.

Then there is the opposite approach: Getting high performance while still using standard sockets, by changing the underbelly with vendor-specific network stacks such as **[OpenOnload](http://www.openonload.org/)'s**. Many of these stacks however only run on the hardware of the specific vendor.